# Find $c_n$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k} x^{n+k}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} c_n x^n$

Tags: summation

For arbitrary coefficients $a_{n,k}$, I am attempting to group by equivalent powers of $x$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n,k} x^{n+k}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} c_n x^n$$

I wish to express $c_n$ as a sum of finitely many $a_{n,k}$.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_{n,k} x^{n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{2N} \left(\sum_{n+k=i} a_{n,k}\right) x^i
$$

Comment: Do you have a simplification for $\sum_{n+k=i}$? My difficulty primarily resides in the efficient characterization of all solutions for $n+k=i$. I had entertained an analogy of counting coefficients in a binomial expansion, but I failed to make substantial progress.

Comment: $$ \sum_{n+k=i}a_{n,k}=\sum_{n=0}^i a_{n,i-n}$$

Comment: That was a clever use of a inhomogeneous Diophantine equation. Thank you.